# How to extract page numbers from citations using Python and regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, bibliography, citations

I'm trying to extract page numbers from citations using regular expressions.

Here is the test data I'm working with:

- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; p. 15
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2: Human Name (1990-2010); p. 15
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2: Human Name (1990-2010); pp. **15-20**
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2: Human Name (1990-2010); pp. 15-
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; **20-25**
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; ISSN: **1234-1234** (Print); **20-25**
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; **20-25**; ISSN: **1234-1234** (Print)
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; ISSN: **1234-1234** (Print); ISSN: **1234-1234** (Online); **20-25**
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; ISSN **1234-1234** (Print); ISSN **1234-1234** (Online); **20-25**

When using the following regex:

```
(?![^()]*\))(\d+-\d+)
```

The values in bold above are matched.

I want to improve that regex to not match any `\d+-\d+` that comes after 'ISSN ' or 'ISSN: '. I've tried adding a look-behind using `(?<![ISSN:?\s])` but had no success.

Any thoughts on how to achieve that and match only the values below?

- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; p. 15
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2: Human Name (1990-2010); p. 15
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2: Human Name (1990-2010); pp. **15-20**
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2: Human Name (1990-2010); pp. 15-
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; **20-25**
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; ISSN: 1234-1234 (Print); **20-25**
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; **20-25**; ISSN: 1234-1234 (Print)
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; ISSN: 1234-1234 (Print); ISSN: 1234-1234 (Online); **20-25**
- Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; ISSN 1234-1234 (Print); ISSN 1234-1234 (Online); **20-25**

Comment: `[ISSN:?\s]` does **not** do what you think... try something like https://regex101.com/#python, which will add an explanation and pretty highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I tried `[ISSN:?\s]` in the beginning of the regex, but that didn't work; it still matches several `1234-1234` in the test string.

Comment: **Read the description**: `[ISSN:?\s]` **match a single character present in the list below**: `ISSN:?` a single character in the list `ISN:?` literally (case sensitive) `\s` match any white space character [`\r\n\t\f`]

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:

```
re.search(r'[^ISN:?](?![^()]*\))\s(\d+-\d+)', s).group(1)
```

Thanks everyone for helping out. Better solutions are still welcome.

Comment: I know you specified a Python solution, but a Ruby gem exists to parse references formatted in any style: https://github.com/inukshuk/anystyle-parser

Answer (score 0):

You can use another negative look ahead with `^` and `$` anchors :

```
^((?!ISSN).)*(?![^()]*\))\s(\d+-\d+)$
```

And note that if you want to apply this regex on a multi-line text you need to use `re.M` flag!that makes the start and end anchors matches the start and end of each line instead of whole of string!

Also you need to add a `\s` before the second group `s(\d+-\d+)` then the second match in your regex will be the desire numbers!

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mR5xT6/2)

```
>>> s="""Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; p. 15
... Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2: Human Name (1990-2010); p. 15
... Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2: Human Name (1990-2010); pp. 15-20
... Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2: Human Name (1990-2010); pp. 15-
... Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; 20-25
... Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; ISSN: 1234-1234 (Print); 20-25
... Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; 20-25; ISSN: 1234-1234 (Print)
... Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; ISSN: 1234-1234 (Print); ISSN: 1234-1234 (Online); 20-25
... Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; ISSN 1234-1234 (Print); ISSN 1234-1234 (Online); 20-25"""
>>> 

>>> re.findall(r'^((?!ISSN).)*(?![^()]*\))\s(\d+-\d+)$',s,re.M)
[('.', '15-20'), (';', '20-25')]
```

And for get the numbers :

```
>>> [i[-1] for i in re.findall(r'^((?!ISSN).)*(?![^()]*\))\s(\d+-\d+)$',s,re.M)]
['15-20', '20-25']
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I tried using it at https://regex101.com/#python and it did not return any match. I used the `g` modifier, as it is not used on a multi-line text.

Comment: @AndréA. Please see the `Demo` i putted the like in answer! https://regex101.com/r/mR5xT6/1

Comment: Thanks for that! But it's not matching `20-25` in `Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; 20-25; ISSN: 1234-1234 (Print)`, for example :(

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. But it still does not match the 20-25 in here:`>>> s = 'Journal Name, Vol. 20, No. 2; 20-25; ISSN: 1234-1234 (Print)'
>>> re.findall(r'^((?!ISSN).)*(?![^()]*\))\s(\d+-\d+)$',s,re.M)
[]`